# Use the Index and Match functions to return a specific cell that contains a key word "VAC"

Tags: excel, search, indexing, match

```
=INDEX('[IHT Schedule 2020.xlsx]Jan - Dec  2021'!$L$18:$AP$79,MATCH($B10,'[IHT Schedule 2020.xlsx]Dec 2020'!$C$18:$C$79,0),MATCH(V$8,'[IHT Schedule 2020.xlsx]Jan - Dec  2021'!$L$17:$AP$17,0))
```

The formula works and returns: `10.5 VAC` from `IHT Schedule2020.xlsx` perfectly.

But I have other cells that may contain `7:30-5:30 am`, or "`off`" , or `UED`.  I  want this formula to search out and return only the "`10.5 VAC`" values.

My question is this possible with this formula or should I be doing this differently?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your result for the text "VAC" and then discard it if not found.

```
=if(isnumber(find("VAC",your formula)),your formula,"")
```

If you have an Office 365 license, you can use the new LET() function to avoid the duplication of the long formula

```
=let(TheResult,your formula,if(isnumber(find("VAC",TheResult)),TheResult,""))
```

Replace `your formula` with the formula you posted in your question, omitting the leading `=` sign.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thank you Teylyn, much appreciated. I'm sorry to ask, but if I wanted multiple criteria like "VAC" and "ABSENCE" would this look right to do?                                                                               =if(isnumber(find("VAC",your formula)),your formula,if(isnumber(find("ABSENT",your formula)),your formula,""))

Comment: You can use an OR() function like this: `=if(or(isnumber(find("VAC",your formula)),isnumber(find("VAC",your formula))),your formula,"")`